# Finding the missing length

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem, geometry

How do i find the ST??

What more information do I need?

I used Pythagorean theorem, but I still can't find the answer.

[image]

Comment: This is for Travis. This thing here is not the only thing I am busy with. I intended to provide the detailed response, but it takes time!!! It seems that the 20K bring some arrogance! May be I am on a trip to Europe... is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try solving it this way. The area of the parallelogram can be determined using two different expressions: (1) by taking the total area of the rectangle and subtracting the triangle areas, and (2) by multiplying the height (unknown) and width of the parallelogram. Set the two equal to each other, and then use the Pythagorean theorem to find the length $ST$.

What answer do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

Now, $y^2=25-x^2=162-(13-x)^2$

Solve for $x$.

Comment: The comment which angered you was deleted, so I edited your solution to remove the reference to it.  Nice solution.

Comment: @Taussig I would suggest that the deletion of an answer will be done after more time and by consensus of at least three - not one 2oK guy.